# how to find roots of cubic equation with unknown real coefficient

Tags: calculus

How can we find roots of cubic equation
$$a x^{3} + b x^{2} + cx +d = 0,$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are real numbers?
If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are known integer, sometimes  we can find its roots by rearrangement of equation, but here how to find the roots?

Comment: [Cubic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Roots_of_a_cubic_function)

Comment: See [Cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: @ Lucian in my equation coefficient a, b, c, d are very large ,is there any another way to find roots because here calculation are very complex?

Comment: @ Alex Becker  in my equation coefficient a, b, c, d are very large so here calculation are very complex, ,is there any another way to find roots??

Comment: If the coefficients are very large, then calculation is going to be complex, no matter what.

Comment: Are you trying to find the exact roots, or numerically within a given tolerance?  If numerically, divide the equation by the absolute value of the largest coefficient*, then apply the cubic formula.  Most CAS have this as a built in function.